# My Spring application does not seem to bind to my configured port

Tags: spring, windows, http, port

Sorry if this is a "Super User" question, it could be a Win-11 quirk?

On the other hand, this issue could be a bad Spring configuration. So, please go easy on me if I got the wrong Stack Exchange - I am still learning!

Also, I unplugged my laptop from the LAN cable and turned off wifi - hopefully this rules out any disturbance from the ISP.

...

- I created a simple Spring application.
  I also gave it a 10-minute wait so that it persists after running the `Application` class...
- I can see a `java.exe` process with the same PID that the Spring start up log is telling me.
- My `application.properties` file is in: `src/main/resources` and it contains: `server.port=7777`
  `server.address=localhost`

I added some code to make the runtime print the current port, EG:
`org.springframework.core.env.Environment.getProperty("server.port");` and the output matches (`7777`)!

However, no api-client I've tried is able to reach that API...
What I've tried:

1. Before running the Spring application, I make sure the port is not taken: `netstat -ano | findstr :7777` (this returns nothing, as no application is listening on this port)
2. I run the application and then try `netstat -ano | findstr :7777` again - **STILL** no application is listening on this port!

I've also added inbound and outbound firewall rules for this port ("allow"). I don't have any special firewall other than what comes with Windows-11

`telnet localhost 7777`
`Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 7777: Connect failed`

---

Logs from running Application:

```
2023-05-29T21:36:23.458+01:00  INFO 13036 --- [           main] 
net.todko.api.Application                : Starting Application 
using Java 19 with PID 13036 
(C:\Storage\Projects\LoadTeacherProto\LoadTeacher\target\classes 
started by ajnyv in 
C:\Storage\Projects\LoadTeacherProto\LoadTeacher)

2023-05-29T21:36:23.467+01:00  INFO 13036 --- [           main] 
net.todko.api.Application                : No active profile set, 
falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

2023-05-29T21:36:24.623+01:00  INFO 13036 --- [           main] 
net.todko.api.Application                : Started Application in 
1.869 seconds (process running for 2.533)
Application is running on port: 7777
Application is running on address: localhost
```

---

My Application class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        Utils.wait(600000);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        printCurrentPort();
    }


    public void printCurrentPort() {
        String port = environment.getProperty("server.port");
        String address = environment.getProperty("server.address");
        System.out.println("Application is running on port: " + port);
        System.out.println("Application is running on address: " + address);
    }
}
```

---

My Async enablement class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ConcurrentConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("ApiThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

---

I also have the BasicController class with the actual API and a Utils.wait() code that I can add to this post, if you think they could be interesting?

Comment: Could you post the logs of your app when it starts please ?

Comment: Do you have any server.address value defined in your application.properties ? Or, if you can add the full file to the post, it would be even better.

Comment: @SebPerp I tried it with server.address=localhost, to no avail. Let me post the whole shebang...

Comment: There is something very strange in your logs. You should have lines of log like : o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 7777 (http) with context path ''.  And I don't understand why you need to make it wait for 10 minutes. If you don't, does your app stop immediately ? Do you have the spring-boot-starter-web dependency in your dependencies ?

Comment: @SebPerp I started this project from maven central archetype, which has some MVC stuff in it. I have the dependdency you mention but I am also starting to suspect the tomcat server is fudged. I will start a new project using the maven initializer and compare the differences